# PHPExcel - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message

Tags: php, excel-formula, phpexcel

I am getting an error everytime I try to export an excel spreadsheet. The error is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Worksheet!J6 -> Worksheet!J6 -> Cyclic Reference in Formula' in /classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:293 Stack trace: 
    #0 /classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php(997): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() 
    #1 /classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php(943): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->_writeCell(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter), Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), 'J6', Array, Array) 
    #2 /classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php(83): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->_writeSheetData(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter), Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), Array) 
    #3 /classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php(282): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->writeWorksheet(Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), Array, false) 
    #4 /includes/reports_funcs.php(620): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('reports/risk-bo...') #5 /createXlsxReport. in /classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 293
```

I tried to look for a solution but so far no luck. I found another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786887/phpexcel-error-cyclic-reference-in-formula) question which suggested adding `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(FALSE);` before the file save, but this gives me an empty spreadsheet.

It has only started happening recently so I am really confused as to why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

SAMPLE CODE - EDIT

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, $pol_ref . 'e' . $end_numb)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $insured_name)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $row, $vessel_name)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $row, $insurance_type . ' - ' . $end_type)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $row, $insured_domicile)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $row, gmdate("d-m-Y",$date_logged))
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $row, $inception_date)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7, $row, $expiry_date)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(8, $row, ($policy_limit == 0.00?$loh_limit:$policy_limit))
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(9, $row, $premium)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(10, $row, "=sum(J".($row)."*".($seacurus_percent/100).")")
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(11, $row, "=sum(J".($row)."*".($placing_percent/100).")")
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, $row, "=sum(J".($row)."*".($rebate_percent/100).")")
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(13, $row, "=sum(J".($row)."*".($iptpercent/100).")")
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(14, $row, "=sum(".($binder_id==6?"(J".$row." - (P".$row."+L".$row."+O".$row."+P".$row."))":"J".($row))."*".$bgn_percent.")")
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(15, $row, "=sum(J".($row)."*".$ghc_percent.")")
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(16, $row, "=sum(J".($row)."*".($commission_percentage_sum/100).")");
$row++;
```

Comment: What version of PHPExcel?

Answer (score 1):

If your formulae contain cyclic references, then you need to choose how to deal with them, as you do in MS Excel itself. The default behaviour is to throw an Exception like this, which is similar to the way MS Excel will behave by default.
The alternative is to tell PHPExcel to follow the cycle for a fixed number of iterations by setting the calculation engine to:

> PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->cyclicFormulaCount = 1;

or to any value > =1 indicating the number of iterations to cycle

> PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->cyclicFormulaCount = 10;

// 10 iteration

Comment: And where would this be placed? Before the file is exported?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. When I add it i get a memory error. When I fix the memory error it doesn't put the data into the spreadsheet

Comment: you should use it before any formula evaluation. so it can handle it before occur

Comment: try before setting values in cell

Comment: If the OP is running PHPExcel 1.7.9 or above, then each PHPExcel object has its own calculation engine, and you need to identify this when calling `PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()` using `PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->cyclicFormulaCount = 1;`