# Circular References in PHPExcel - infinite loop or wrong result

Tags: phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel 1.8.0

I have read the posts regarding circular references, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786887/phpexcel-error-cyclic-reference-in-formula), but I am still running into issues.

1. If a spreadsheet contains one circular ref. formula, PHPExcel's calculations do not match MS Excel.
2. If a spreadsheet contains more than one circular ref, then PHPExcel goes into an infinite loop.

Here are the details of what I've done so far.

Assume a spreadsheet where A1 = B1 and B1 = A1+1, and Excel is set to 100 iterations. Here is my code:

```
// create reader
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

// load workbook
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($this->_path);

// set iterative calculations max count
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->cyclicFormulaCount = 100;

// calculate
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Testing');
$data = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:B1');

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($data);
echo '</pre>';

// release resources
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objPHPExcel);
```

MSExcel results in A1 = 99, B1 = 100. My code produces this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #VALUE!
            [1] => #VALUE!
        )
)
```

Further to that, if I add A2 = B2 and B2 = A2+1, and attempt to calculate (A1:B2), it goes into an infinite loop and eventually crashes:

**Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cgc\bulldog\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 2837**

Here is what I've done so far. In _calculateFormulaValue in Calculation.php:

Line 2383: `$cellValue = '';` - this is the cause of the #Value! error. I changed that to `$cellValue = 0;`

Line 2400:

```
} elseif ($this->_cyclicFormulaCell == '') {
    $this->_cyclicFormulaCell = $wsTitle.'!'.$cellID;
```

This is the cause of the infinite loop. $this->_cyclicFormulaCell does not get re-set to '' after the formula in row 1 is done, so this condition does not work for the formula in row 2.

I fixed this as follows, starting from Line 2389:

```
    if (($wsTitle{0} !== "\x00") && ($this->_cyclicReferenceStack->onStack($wsTitle.'!'.$cellID))) {
        if ($this->cyclicFormulaCount <= 0) {
            return $this->_raiseFormulaError('Cyclic Reference in Formula');
        } elseif (($this->_cyclicFormulaCount >= $this->cyclicFormulaCount) &&
                  ($this->_cyclicFormulaCell == $wsTitle.'!'.$cellID)) {
            // Olga - reset for next formula
            $this->_cyclicFormulaCell = '';
            return $cellValue;
        } elseif ($this->_cyclicFormulaCell == $wsTitle.'!'.$cellID) {
            ++$this->_cyclicFormulaCount;
            if ($this->_cyclicFormulaCount >= $this->cyclicFormulaCount) {
                // Olga - reset for next formula
                $this->_cyclicFormulaCell = '';
                return $cellValue;
            }
        } elseif ($this->_cyclicFormulaCell == '') {
            $this->_cyclicFormulaCell = $wsTitle.'!'.$cellID;
            if ($this->_cyclicFormulaCount >= $this->cyclicFormulaCount) {
                // Olga - reset for next formula
                $this->_cyclicFormulaCell = '';
                return $cellValue;
            }
        }
```

After these fixes, if I run `$data = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:B2');`, I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100 // should be 99
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100 // should be 99
            [1] => 100
        )
)
```

As you can see, the results from PHPExcel are not consistent with MS Excel. Why is this happening and how can I get around this?

Comment: Why is it happening? Because the developer isn't a machine, and is capable of making mistakes. How can you get round it? Identify the exact cause (e.g. should the check be `$this->_cyclicFormulaCount > $this->cyclicFormulaCount` rather than `$this->_cyclicFormulaCount >= $this->cyclicFormulaCount`, test and prove it, and submit a PR to github

Comment: In the meanwhile, I'll take a look myself.... `$cellValue = ''` should really be dependent on the cell styling, not always set to 0

Comment: PS. Thanks for the detailed analysis.... most people who encounter problems simply say "it don't work" (often without ever saying what exactly doesn't work.... and just expect me to fix it for them

Comment: Looks like I need to store the iteration count for each individual cell in the cycle, so a bit more complex than I'd first thought

Comment: Mark, thanks so much for your replies. I am sorry, when I asked "why is this happening" I didn't mean to offend - just wanted a clarification on the algorithm. Anyway, I fixed it, and I am posting the answer below.

Comment: For reference, both your initialisation of `$cellValue` - though I'm setting it to a NULL rather than a 0 to prevent problems with formulae working with strings - and the reset of `$this->_cyclicFormulaCell` have been pushed to the develop branch on github

Comment: A part of the problem that I found was the order in which cells are calculated (left to right, then row by row) but I haven't identified a satisfactory solution: my thinking was to modify the calculation cache to hold both the calculated value of a cell, and the number of iterations that had been executed

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done. In my case the formula converges, so the precise order of calculations is not important. I ended up doing a pass through the entire stack, to calculate all cells once. Then when the whole stack is done, I do it all over again cyclicFormulaCount times. I hope my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to debug this. My spreadsheet was very complicated, lots of circular refs. The most challenging is a scenario where A depends on B, B depends on both A and C, and C depends on B.

I also added a maxChange parameter, so the thing works like Excel. Otherwise it takes too long on my spreadsheet.

Anyway, here is a usage example:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objCalc = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel);
$objCalc->cyclicFormulaCount = 100;
$objCalc->maxChange = 0.001;
```

The two files that were modified are: Calculation.php and CalcEngine/CyclicReferenceStack.php

Here is the code (sorry Mark, I can't afford more time to submit it to git properly).

## Calculation.php

add these to class properties:

```
private $_precedentsStack = array();
public $maxChange = 0;
```

replace _calculateFormulaValue() function with this:

```
public function _calculateFormulaValue($formula, $cellID=null, PHPExcel_Cell $pCell = null) {
    $this->_debugLog->writeDebugLog("BREAKPOINT: _calculateFormulaValue for $cellID");

    //  Basic validation that this is indeed a formula
    //  We simply return the cell value if not
    $formula = trim($formula);
    if ($formula{0} != '=') return self::_wrapResult($formula);
    $formula = ltrim(substr($formula,1));
    if (!isset($formula{0})) return self::_wrapResult($formula);

    // initialize values
    $pCellParent = ($pCell !== NULL) ? $pCell->getWorksheet() : NULL;
    $wsTitle = ($pCellParent !== NULL) ? $pCellParent->getTitle() : "\x00Wrk";
    $key = $wsTitle.'!'.$cellID;
    $data = array(
        'i' => 0,  // incremented when the entire stack has been calculated
        'j' => 0,  // flags the formula as having been calculated; can only be 0 or 1
        'cellValue' => $pCell->getOldCalculatedValue(), // default value to start with
        'precedents' => array(),
        'holdValue' => FALSE // set to TRUE when change in value is less then maxChange
    );

    // add this as precedent
    $this->_precedentsStack[] = $key;

    // if already been calculated, return cached value
    if (($cellID !== NULL) && ( $this->getValueFromCache($wsTitle, $cellID, $cellValue))) {
        return $cellValue;
    }

    $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->getValueByKey($key, $data);
    extract($data);
    $this->_debugLog->writeDebugLog("iteration # $i");

    // if already calculated in this iteration, return the temp cached value
    if ($i >= $this->cyclicFormulaCount || $j == 1) {
        return $cellValue;
    }

    // on stack, but has not yet been calculated => return default value
    if (($wsTitle{0} !== "\x00") && ($this->_cyclicReferenceStack->onStack($key))) {

        if ($this->cyclicFormulaCount <= 0) {
            return $this->_raiseFormulaError('Cyclic Reference in Formula');
        }

        return $cellValue;
    }

    // calculate value recursively      
    $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->push($key);
    $cellValue = $this->_processTokenStack($this->_parseFormula($formula, $pCell), $cellID, $pCell);
    $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->pop();

    // everything in precedent stack after the current cell is a precedent
    // and every precedent's precedent is a precedent (aka a mouthfull)
    while ( $this->_precedentsStack[ count($this->_precedentsStack) - 1 ] != $key ){
        $data['precedents'][] = array_pop($this->_precedentsStack);
    }
    $data['precedents'] = array_unique($data['precedents']);

    // check for max change
    $oldValue = $this->_extractResult($data['cellValue']);
    $newValue = $this->_extractResult($cellValue);
    $data['cellValue'] = $cellValue;
    $data['holdValue'] = (abs($oldValue - $newValue) < $this->maxChange);

    // flag as calculated and save to temp storage
    $data['j'] = 1;
    $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->setValueByKey($key, $data);

    // if this cell is a precedent, trigger a re-calculate
    $tempCache = $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->showValues();
    foreach ($tempCache as $tempKey => $tempData) {
        if ( $tempData['holdValue'] == TRUE && ( in_array($key, $tempData['precedents'])) ) {
            $tempData['holdValue'] = FALSE;
        }
        $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->setValueByKey($tempKey, $tempData);
    }

    // at the end of the stack, increment the counter and flag formulas for re-calculation
    if (count($this->_cyclicReferenceStack->showStack()) == 0) {
        $i++;
        $this->_precedentsStack = array();

        $tempCache = $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->showValues();
        foreach ($tempCache as $tempKey => $tempData) {
            $tempData['i'] = $i;
            if ( ! $tempData['holdValue'] ) $tempData['j'] = 0;

            $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->setValueByKey($tempKey, $tempData);
        }

        $this->_debugLog->writeDebugLog("iteration # $i-1 finished");
    }

    if ($i < $this->cyclicFormulaCount) {
        $cellValue = $this->_calculateFormulaValue($pCell->getValue(), $cellID, $pCell);
    } elseif ($cellID !== NULL) {
        // all done: move value from temp storage to cache
        $this->saveValueToCache($wsTitle, $cellID, $cellValue);
        $this->_cyclicReferenceStack->removeValueByKey($key);
    }

    //  Return the calculated value
    return $cellValue;

}   //  function _calculateFormulaValue()
```

add this helper function:

```
private function _extractResult($result) {
    if (is_array($result)) {
        while (is_array($result)) {
            $result = array_pop($result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

## CyclicReferenceStack.php

add a property:

```
private $_values = array();
```

add a bunch of functions:

```
public function setValueByKey($key, $value) {
    $this->_values[$key] = $value;
}

public function getValueByKey($key, &$value) {
    if (isset($this->_values[$key])) {
        $value = $this->_values[$key];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function removeValueByKey($key) {
    if (isset($this->_values[$key])) {
        unset($this->_values[$key]);
    }
}

public function showValues() {
    return $this->_values;
}
```