# PHPExcel Sum Function Yields to Corrupted Excel FIle

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having issue for days now and couldn't figure out what's the issue. I appreciate any help. So, I am trying to put the total of a column in a cell in an excel file generated using phpexcel however the generated excel gets corrupted everytime I use the function SUM(). Function COUNT(), MIN(), etc. works just fine. The code is as follows:

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
    $col = 0; $field_count = 0;
    foreach($d as $cell)
    {    
         $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $cell); 
         $col++; $field_count++;
    }
    $row++;
}

$sheet->setCellValue('E'.$row, 'Grand Total:' );
$sheet->setCellValue('F'.$row, '=SUM(F5:F'.($row-1).')');
//$sheet->setCellValue('G'.$row, '=COUNT(F5:F'.($row-1).')');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Here's the error I am getting everytime I use SUM:

[image]

Comment: can't you sum in php and add the correct value ? otherwise you might need to add `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);` to allow formulas

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I need to sum at least 5 different columns. I will look into `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);`. Thanks!

Comment: From the Excel error message, something else is being written into the file output stream.... try opening the file in a text editor, and looking for any plaintext PHP messages that might be visible

Comment: @MarkBaker You were right. And the error I got has reference to your answer from another question. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786887/phpexcel-error-cyclic-reference-in-formula) . LOL Thanks man!!